# Order is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

i have this in my index. However, the Order is not working . Can i have some feedback on where it goes wrong ?

**Generator index**

```
def index
    @generators=Generator.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

**Result index**

```
 def index
    @results=Result.all
  end
```

this is the **Log**

```
Started GET "/generators" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-22 13:18:20 +0800
Processing by GeneratorsController#index as HTML
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (2.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 1]]
  ←[1m←[35mGenerator Load (3.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "generators".* FROM "generators" WHERE "generators"."user_id" = $1  [["user_
id", 1]]
  ←[1m←[36mResult Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "results".* FROM "results" WHERE "results"."generator_id" = $1 ORDER BY "re
sults"."id" ASC LIMIT 1←[0m  [["generator_id", 10]]
  ←[1m←[35mResult Load (2.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "results".* FROM "results" WHERE "results"."generator_id" = $1 ORDER BY "result
s"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["generator_id", 14]]
```

**index page**

This is the generator index page. There's no result index page

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="view_index">
        <h2 align="center">Primer Generated Results</h2>
            <p align ="center"><font size ="5"><strong>*** <u>Click Analyze for Binding-Time Analysis</u> *** </p></font></strong>  

<table class="index">
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="no_col">Primer length</th>
              <th class="sstring_col">Method used</th>
              <th class="rpg_col">Random primer generated <b>[5'->3']</b></th>
              <th class="no_col">T<sub>m</sub> (<sup>o</sup>C)</th>
              <th class="string_col">Generated Time (UTC +8:00)</th>
              <th class="sstring_col">Reference sequence</th>
              <th class="gs_col">Description of reference sequence</th>
              <th class="no_col">Binding of primer (no.of times)</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
            <% current_user.generators.each do |generator| %>
          <tr class="result">
                <td align="center"><%= generator.primer_length %></td>
                <td align="center"><%= generator.choice %></td>
                <td>               <%= generator.random_primer_generated %></td>
                <td align="center"><%= generator.melting_temp %><sup>o</sup>C</td>
                <td>               <%= generator.created_at %></td>

                <% if generator.result.present? %>
                        <% if generator.result.ncbi_ref_seq.blank?%>
                            <td> NIL </td>
                            <td> SAMPLE </td>
                            <td align="center"><%= generator.result.binding_times %></td>
                        <%else%>
                            <td>               <%= generator.result.ncbi_ref_seq %></td>
                            <td>               <%= generator.result.genome_sample %></td>
                            <td align="center"><%= generator.result.binding_times %></td>
                        <%end%>
                <td id="change"><%= link_to 'Details',generator_result_path(:generator_id=>generator.id, :id=>generator.result.id) %></td>
                <td id="change"><%= link_to 'Delete',generator, :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                <% else %>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="change"><%= link_to 'Analyze',generator_path(generator) %></td>
                    <td id="change"><%= link_to 'Delete',generator,:method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                <% end %>
         </tr>
             <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? Are you using `@generators` anywhere?

Comment: Do you have another `@generators = ` line somewhere, possible related to users? (e.g. `@generators = user.generators`)

Comment: yes i am sure that will work

Comment: @muistooshort well because i'm trying to have DESC but the order is still ASC :/

Comment: @DylanMarkow yes i have them in my Generator create action. `@generator = current_user.generators.build(params[:generator])`

Comment: Where are you using `@generators`? I don't see anything that would actually execute the `Generator.order("created_at DESC")` query and I don't see it in the logs.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm using them in index page however it's not giving me DESC. That is what i'm trying to solve. I have got no idea how come it doesn't work

Comment: How specifically are you using it in your index page? Your logs show now evidence whatsoever that you're using that `@generators` so the problem is in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: @muistooshort u mean my index page how i call the generator ?

Comment: Yes, how are you using `@generators`. Just saying `Generator.order("created_at DESC")` doesn't hit the database, that is simply building a query.

Comment: current_user.generators doesn't access @generators. in case you like to go with current_user.generators us a scope there like `current_user.generators.ordered`. you have to define the scope first.

Comment: @muistooshort i see. so how should i fix them now ?

Comment: @wkaha how should i do that defining scope ?? What if i want to go with the current-user.generators. i want them to order by descen

Comment: you can set a default scope in generator model default_scope order('created_at DESC')

Comment: In practical terms, invoking `.all`, or `.each`...etc, would make the actual DB call. Up until that point, no DB call has been made (hence the log). So that is what Mu was asking: where in the `index` view code do you call one of those methods on the `@generator` object. One way you can do the order by on the `current_users.generators` relation, is to simply append your `order("created_at DESC")` at the end, so it looks like `current_users.generators.order("created_at DESC")`. Or NitinJ's method works better too, if you want to ensure its ALWAYS ordered whenever `generator` objects are loaded.

Comment: @NitinJ: Want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: @muistooshort yes. posted it as an answer

Comment: alright. Thanks for the explaination. Thank you very much every1 =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set a default scope in Generator model

```
default_scope order('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Generator.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: ... and def index @results=Result.all.order(string) end